# Insert at given position in link list , in code why we need (pos-2)

Tags: c++, for-loop, linked-list

In the code given below we insert a node at a given position.

My question is: Why do we need to use `pos-2` in the `for` condition?

```c
insertNode(Node *head,int pos,int data)
{
    Node *temp=new Node(data);
    if(pos==1)
    {
        temp->next=head;
        return temp;
    }
    Node * curr=head;
    for(int i=1;i<=pos-2 && curr!=NULL ;i++)
        curr=curr->next;

    if(curr==NULL)
        return head;

    temp->next=curr->next;
    curr->next=temp;
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to note:

We want `curr` to point to the node that *precedes* the position where the new node is to be inserted. This is because we will make the insertion happen with `curr->next=temp`, where `temp` is the new node.

Since the head node has no predecessor, it is a special case. This occurs when `pos` is 1.

When `pos` is 2, the preceding node is the head node. Since `curr` is initialised as `head`, it should not move. So also for this case, we don't want the loop to make any iterations.

When `pos` is 3, the preceding node is the *second* node in the list. Since `curr` points at `head`, it needs to make one step forward, i.e. the loop should iterate just once. This happens when you make the `for` condition as  `<=pos-2`.

Alternatively, you could reason that we have already dealt with the case where `pos` is 1, so we could let the loop start at `pos=2`, and then we can also replace the `<=` with `<` which denotes that we want to get to the *preceding* position, not **at** the position. And now the loop header looks like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i < pos && curr != NULL; i++)
```

This performs the same number of iterations, but maybe it is more readable.

I hope this explains it.